# Dependency inversion always includes dependency injection?

Tags: design

This is a question on a home work. I've been up and down my notes and I can't even see how the two are related. Googling this gives me questions/answers on one or the other, but never both.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does you no good if the internet does your homework.

Comment: @Telastyn No, it is not off-topic. The fact that it is his homework is not relevant in this case. He tried to search for the answer, but without success

Comment: Telastyn, I've spent my whole weekend trying to find an answer to this question. My notes have been a waste of time, and googling has been less than fruitful. There comes a point when I can't take it anymore and that is when I end up here.

Comment: recommended reading: **[Open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6166/31260)**

Comment: So my answer got a down-vote because answering at all is morally objectionable to someone?

Comment: @gnat: While that open letter is well-written and good reading, pasting a link without explanation like that could be seen as implying that the OP is not following its suggestions, when he clearly is.

Comment: @BЈовић - then don't vote to close. I will gleefully vote to close any homework question (though not anyone who chooses to answer). The entire point of the homework is for user106857 to _think_ about how these two concepts are related. Programmers' entire careers are based on being able to think through problems and devise a solution. Doing it for him/her is doing them a huge disservice.

Comment: @Telastyn: It's a good thing, then, that some community members actually contributed some insightful answers.  It's doubly good that these answers happen to be useful to others.  We were all students, at one time or another, and we all struggled with answering a question that couldn't be answered at all because we didn't understand either the vocabulary or the underlying concepts.  It's difficult to formulate a solution to a problem when you don't even know what the problem is.  We've all been there.

Comment: @Telastyn: Voting to close a question because it's got the dreaded h-word in it is silly.  First, any lazy student who realizes this will just post the same homework question without putting in the h-word.  Second, it messes with honest, non-lazy students who have a good question and have made an effort of their own.  By your logic, anyone who asks any question (whether or not it's related to homework) is incompetent, because they should have been able to just think about it themselves.

Comment: @MichaelShaw - Not incompetent, but also not learning what they're supposed to be. Certainly students will run into problems, but asking "please answer my question" does not gain them very much compared to actually thinking through the problem. To do that well requires a **discussion** - with a teacher, with an expert, with a rubber duck to bounce ideas off of. This site is not an appropriate forum for discussions.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - (in addition to my comment for Mr. Shaw) - certainly, but the OP didn't ask to clarify underlying concepts or vocabulary.

Comment: @Telastyn: Nor did I say we should.

Comment: @Telastyn: None of what you're saying applies only to students.  If what you're saying is true, it applies equally to all other questions on the site.  I don't think asking a question is an abdication of thinking or that answering a question well requires a discussion forum, whether or not the question asker has homework.  If you have a legitimate problem with the question, you would still have a problem with it if the asker was a professional with no homework.

Comment: The 'danger' of seeking *answers* (thats what SE is about) is that we can give right answers that are completely wrong for what was covered in the course notes or what the instructor is seeking. This tends not to be an issue in the 'real world' - the answer that works, works. Furthermore, the answer may provide an understanding that skips steps that are critical to the curriculum and the next assignment (not an issue in the 'real world'). Getting the full scope of the question and concepts (the interaction and discussion) is often best with the instructor, or failing that [chat].

Answer (score 9):

Dependency Injection is a technique for implementing Dependency Inversion.

The [Inversion of Control page on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_Control#Implementation_techniques) actually says it a little better, even though Dependency Inversion and Inversion of Control may not be *exactly* the same thing.

Here is what it says:

> ### Implementation Techniques
>
> In object-oriented programming, there are several basic techniques to
>   implement inversion of control. These are:
>
> - using a factory pattern
> - using a service locator pattern
> - using a dependency injection, for example:
>
>   - Constructor injection
>   - Parameter injection
>   - Setter injection
>   - Interface injection
> - using a contextualized lookup
> - using Template method design pattern
> - using Strategy design pattern

So no, Dependency Injection is not the only way to accomplish Dependency Inversion.

Comment: I think this answer is not correct. In several patterns that you mention such as factories, method template, strategy,  you still mantain transisties dependecies with the concrete class. There fore at this point you are not achieving DIP. 
The only way to eliminate this dependencies at compile-time is to use some abstration. Once you client code start to depend of abstraction the only way to priovide them at runtime is by dependecies injection mechanisim.
So the short answear is yes, at the end of the path(runtime) you will need a dependecy injection mechanisim in order to archive DIP.

Comment: Dependency inversion isn't about eliminating dependencies; it's about the [Hollywood Principle.](https://deviq.com/principles/hollywood-principle)

Answer (score 8):

Answer: No. Here's the difference:

[Dependency Inversion is a **principle**](http://www.oodesign.com/dependency-inversion-principle.html).

> High-level modules should not depend on low-level modules. Both should
>   depend on abstractions. Abstractions should not depend on details.
>   Details should depend on abstractions.

Dependency Injection is a **technique**, whereupon the dependencies -- rather, their abstractions -- are explicitly injected into an object, typically into the constructor, but sometimes exposed as properties. This can be done with [**Poor Man's DI** or with an **IoC Container**](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/11/06/WhentouseaDIContainer/).

**Example of Poor Man's DI:**

```
public class ConsumingClass
{
    private readonly ISomeService SomeService;

    public ConsumingClass(ISomeService someService)
    {
        SomeService = someService ?? new SomeServiceConcrete().
    }

    /* use SomeService elsewhere in the class */
}
```

**Example of DI with IoC:**

```
public class ConsumingClass
{
    private readonly ISomeService SomeService;

    public ConsumingClass(ISomeService someService)
    {
        SomeService = someService.
    }

    /* use SomeService elsewhere in the class */
}
```

The [Service Locator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern), in contrast to Dependency Injection, requires the object to ask a service for its dependencies. This is considered an anti-pattern. The details of why is beyond the scope of the question and is left as an exercise for the reader.

**Example of Service Locator:**

```
public class ConsumingClass
{
    private readonly ISomeService SomeService;

    public ConsumingClass()
    {
        SomeService = SomeServiceLocator.GetInstance<ISomeService>();
    }

    /* use SomeService elsewhere in the class */
}
```

Comment: What is the ISomeService doing in the second example?

Comment: The SomeService member is being assigned an instance of ISomeService. I assumed that the service locator would have a generic method GetInstance<T>() that would then return an instance of ISomeService.

Answer (score 0):

[The wiki page on *Dependency inversion principle*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) tells :

> Various patterns such as Plugin, Service Locator, or Dependency
>   Injection are then employed to facilitate the run-time provisioning of
>   the chosen low-level component implementation to the high-level
>   component.

Therefore, the answer is : dependency injection is a technique to apply the dependency inversion principle, but it is not the only one.

There are other techniques when you want to use this principle (the linked wiki page lists plugins and service locator as additional techniques).

The dependency injection is a specific kind of inversion of control in a way that you somehow inject a lower level object into higher level object. That way, the higher level object depends on an abstraction - and not on the concrete implementation of a lower level object. In other words, it access an object through it's (usually abstract) interface.

Comment: How does this relate to the OP's question?  Remember, they're a student just learning this, and you're handing them a *lot* of technical terms and programmer jargon.

Comment: @RobertHarvey How it doesn't relate? The question is "Dependency inversion always includes dependency injection?", and it provides clear answer. What kind of details is missing?

Comment: I'll rephrase my comment.  *Explain it in plain English.*  There's plenty of time for vocabulary lessons later.  This is the burden you carry when you take on homework questions.  Your quote does explain it, but in a way that reads like a Dilbert mission statement.

Comment: Wait, so Dependency Inversion always includes dependency interjection? There are no instances where it would not?

Comment: @user106857 No, as I said, there are other techniques to apply the dependency inversion. If you are familiar with C or C++, you can also apply dependency injection by loading a shared library at run time (that is how are plugins usually implemented)

Answer (score -3):

The simple answer to your question is "No, Dependency Injection is not always present when Dependency Inversion is used."

Simply put, "Dependency Inversion" is the principle and "Dependency Injection" is just one method of implementation. As noted in another answer, there are other implementations of the principle including Service Locators and Plug-In Frameworks.